# I need a hint for basic scripting in CryEngine 3

Tags: lua, cryengine

I want to add some Parameters to the Player. e.g "Hunger", "Thirst" (Survival Stuff)
Can I do this with a lua script? Because the Player is something that's already set up in the engine. Can I acess him?
Or what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the case that the player is immutable or you're otherwise unable to add new fields to it (*userdata, etc.*), then it's usually possible to construct a table which has the unchangeable data (*in this case, the player*) as an index key to fields representing the data you want to track.

```
local hunger = setmetatable({}, {__mode = 'k'}) -- Use weak keys for the GC.
hunger[Player1] = 10
```

For example, you could use this idiom any time you wanted to "add" more information to such an object, userdata, or table. This is just a general Lua idea, separate from any specific engine. Depending upon how CryEngine works, you might need to make `hunger` a global variable as opposed to a local one.